# Shelveset in VSTS (git) with VS2017

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, shelveset

**How can I create a shelveset with VS2017 (using VSTS and git)?**

Within the Team Explorer in VS2017, there is no button for shelveset available, just for commit.

Do I have to activate it? Or isn't it available for the current VSTS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're searching for the tools about TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control). Git is a completely different source control system and the tools provided by Visual Studio are different, too.

[Here you can find a comparison between Git and TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/vsts/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=vsts).

Comment: Ah so the solution with VSTS and git is to just create a new branch

Comment: A shelveset is a commit in the git world. I don't know your specific needs but [here there is a mapping of TFVC actions VS git](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/vsts/repos/git/mapping-my-tfvc-actions-to-git?toc=%2Fvsts%2Frepos%2Ftfvc%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvsts%2Frepos%2Ftfvc%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts&tabs=command-line)

Comment: @MicheleFerracin That is incorrect. A shelveset is not equivalent to a commit. The closest equivalent to a TFVC shelveset in Git would be `stash`.

Comment: As mentioned by @DanielMann, `stash` is the closest - I use it all the time. Here is a great article that might help anyone looking for it in VS 2019 - https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/10/the-git-stash-functionality-in-visual-studio-2019/